# How to find partial sum of series and prove convergence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2n+3}{2^{n-1}}$$
How to find partial sum, sum of series and prove convergence?
May be we can use some geometric series.

Comment: it's not geometric. Try a comparison test with $2^{-n}$

Comment: any thoughts by your own?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**. One may start with the standard *finite* evaluation:
$$
1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^n=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}, \quad |x|<1. \tag1
$$ Then by differentiating $(1)$ we have
$$
1+2x+3x^2+\cdots+nx^{n-1}=\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{(1-x)^2}+\frac{-(n+1)x^{n}}{1-x}, \quad |x|<1, \tag2
$$ then by considering $2\times (2)+3 \times (1)$ with $x=\dfrac12$ one gets the desired partial sum.

Answer (score 4):

HINT: prove by induction that the finite sum is given by
$$\sum_{n=1}^k\frac{2n+3}{2^{n-1}}=2^{1-k} \left(-2 k+7\ 2^k-7\right)$$